# for loop and in operator in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to understand existing code, written in python. I am currently learning python. Can someone help me understand this piece of code?

```
bits_list = split_string_into_chunks(coding, n)
# take first bit as the sign, and the remaining bits as integers
signs_nums = [(-1 if bits[0] == '0' else 1, int(bits[1:], 2)) 
                  for bits in bits_list]
# use modulo to ensure that the numbers fall within the require interval:
#   -2.048 ≤ x ≤ 2.048
x = [sign * (num % 2.048) for sign, num in signs_nums]
```

Comment: What is it you don't understand? [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

Comment: Note that there is not a single ``in`` operator in your code. ``for <name> in <expression>`` is a compound statement where ``in`` is not the containment operator. The last comment is also incorrect - ``num % 2.048`` excludes the borders; the range is -2.048 < x < 2.048.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bits_list = split_string_into_chunks(coding, n)

This line of code calls a function split_string_into_chunks, taking 2 parameters, what they are you don't show. bits_list is the return value which looks like a dataframe list or dictionary object

signs_nums = [(-1 if bits[0] == '0' else 1, int(bits[1:], 2)) 
                  for bits in bits_list]

The use of the square brackets tells me that this is something called list comprehension. For that, I always start at the end of the line.

```
for bits in bits_list - This part of the line says I have a list of values and the for loop will process each element of the list via the variable 'bits'.

-1 if bits[0] == '0' - This if statement is a little backwards. what is saying is I will return the number -1 if the first value of bits is equal to 0. From this statement, it apprears that bits is actually a value pair listing which means that bits_list is probably a python dict object.

else 1 - this is the else part of the if above if statement. So if the value of bits[0] is not equal to 0 then I will return 1.

int(bits[1:], 2) - This part is interesting as it converts the bits[1:] to binary.

sign_nums - this is the returned list of binary values based
```

x = [sign * (num % 2.048) for sign, num in signs_nums]

Again this is using list comprehension. With this construct, I find it easier to start from the right and move left. So breaking it down;

```
sign_nums - is a python dictionary or two-dimensional array object which the for loop will loop over.
num - is an individual value from the sign_nums dictionary object.
sign - is the second element from the sings_num dictionary that is associated with num.
The for loop will pull out individual value pair items from signs_nums.

sign * (num % 2.048) the first part in brackets takes the modulus of num divided by 2.048 and then multiplies that by whatever is in sign
x - this is the returned list from the line of code, which happens to be the answer to the sum sign * (num % 2.048).
```

Comment: thank you!! also can you tell what does a * mean in python like in the line  
`fitness = lambda coding: obj_fun(*decoder(coding))` or 
`def rosenbrock_OF(*x):`

Comment: using the asterisk (*)  character before a variable as in  def rosenbrock_OF(*x): means the function will take an arbitrary number of positional variables. You will only use it if the number variables to be passed to the function is not known at 'compile time'. What I mean is the number of positional variables can be 0 or  more